# How to reload full screen in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I would like to reload everything after going back to the screen. Like it is done in `useEffect/componentDidMount`. Task which I'm trying to solve: I have some remotely based translations tool from which I fetch strings for everything like labels, buttons, hints for inputs and so on. On the "Settings" screen where I select another language I download from the api the new strings. And then after loading these new strings I would like to update my UI. I have such screen:

```
const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [logInStr, setLogin] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [reloadUI, setReload] = useState(false);
  let commonData = CommonDataManager.getInstance();

  const handleEmail = text => {
    setLogin(text);
  };
  const handlePassword = text => {
    setPassword(text);
  };

  const languagePress = () => {
    setReload(true);
    navigation.navigate('LanguageScr');
  };

  const updUI = () => {
    
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      updUI();
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => languagePress()}>
        <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>Language</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={[{flex: 1}, styles.elementsContainer]}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#EE2C38'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#FAA030'}} />
        <View style={{flex: 3, backgroundColor: '#32B76C'}}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder={commonData.getStrings()[11001]}
            placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            multiline={false}
            onChangeText={handleEmail}
          />

          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder={commonData.getStrings()[10948]}
            placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            multiline={false}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            onChangeText={handlePassword}
          />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitButton} onPress={() => ...}>
            <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>
              {commonData.getStrings()[12078]}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

and here as you can see I have listener which will be triggered only after returning to this screen. I got to know about: `this.forceUpdate();` but I got an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` in my `updateUI` method. So, how I can do it? Maybe full reloading is not good solution and you will suggest me to use some state strings for such screen, but what if I use screen with more strings (>20) for example? So I will have to use 20 state elements? I think it is not also very logical, or I don't understand anything in it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have managed to find the own solution for this task. As I said that for me it looks not good to make a lot of state variables for all fields. But I thought what if I will created one single map for all strings which will be equal for the apps' strings storage which will be updated after returning to the screen from which I went to the language screen. And below you can see the final colution:

```
const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  ....
  const [map, setStrings] = useState(
    CommonDataManager.getInstance().getStrings(),
  );

  ....

  const updUI = () => {
    setStrings(CommonDataManager.getInstance().getStrings());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      updUI();
    });
  }, [navigation]);

   .....

}
```

and all fields, labels and buttons titles are from this state map which will be updated :)